# Explaination to tag issue in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uitableview, tags, uitapgesturerecognizer

This is not a massive issue with me, I am just struggling to understand what is happening. Other rather how to make it work the way I want it to work.

Consider the following code of any standard UITableViewController:

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customCellID) as? CustomTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        print("Inside cellForRowAt: \(indexPath.row)")

        customCell.backgroundColor = .red
        
        tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tagIndexPathRowMethod))
        tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapGestureRecognizer.view?.tag = indexPath.row
        
        customCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        customCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        
        return customCell
        
    } else {

        print("Inside cellForRowAt: \(indexPath.row)")

        customCell.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tagIndexPathRowMethod))
        tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapGestureRecognizer.view?.tag = indexPath.row
        
        customCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        customCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        
        return customCell
    }
}

@objc private func tagIndexPathRowMethod(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Cell number tag: \(String(describing: sender.view?.tag))")
}
```

I've already tried splitting the properties, methods and cells into separate codes such as

```
var firstTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
var secondTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

etc, but the tag still prints only a 0 from both cells.

Could someone explain to me how to make the print statement in tagIndexPathRowMethod returns 0 as tag no matter if I tap in cell 0 or cell 1, but the print statements inside cellForRowAt prints the correct indexPath.row integers, 0 and 1? I know I could use didSelectRowAt, but I've just become stubborn I guess.

(I'm well aware of all times I'm breaking with the DRY principle, but it just serves as a pedagogical example.)

Comment: I just wanted to understand why you are trying to add tap gesture while there is already a delegate method didSelectRowAtIndex path?

Comment: For several reasons, like designing custom UITableViewCells. I might want to keep a UITextField in one cell and a UIButton in the other one, etc.

Comment: You can do that all but the end goal is tapping on a particular cell and getting an index of that particular cell right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct :)

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there anything more you'd like me to provide?

Comment: Maybe someone not finds it relevant. But for me, this question was learning :) so I consider it should be upvoted.

Comment: Thank you! Does questions get voted on for being relevant or irrelevant? I thought questions should be up or downvoted based on the structure of the question, whether it has been ask before, if the questioner is providing sufficient code, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Updated answer

This happening because the you setting tag before adding gestures to the cell. In this case, tapGestureRecognizer.view is null at that time. Just do one thing set tag after adding gestures to the cell.

```
   customCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
   
   tapGestureRecognizer.view?.tag = indexPath.row
```

Comment: Yes, I should have said that I have already tried the didSelectRowAt method, but it renders the UITapGestureRecognizer redundant. Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: FYI, I update my answer hope this will work for you

Comment: Yup, this is the correct way to do it! I tested it myself. Much obliged :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of view tag inside the UITapGestureRecognizer class. Just add the line below after initializing 'customCell'.

customCell.tag = indexPath.row

Code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customCellID) as? CustomTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    customCell.tag = indexPath.row

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        print("Inside cellForRowAt: \(indexPath.row)")

        customCell.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tagIndexPathRowMethod))
        tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapGestureRecognizer.view?.tag = indexPath.row
        
        customCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        customCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        
        return customCell
        
    } else {

        print("Inside cellForRowAt: \(indexPath.row)")

        customCell.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tagIndexPathRowMethod))
        tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapGestureRecognizer.view?.tag = indexPath.row
        
        customCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        customCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        
        return customCell
    }
}

@objc private func tagIndexPathRowMethod(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Cell number tag: \(String(describing: sender.view?.tag))")
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is the code provided in this answer different from my own code?

Comment: You need to set value of view tag inside the UITapGestureRecognizer class.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please see the correct answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `cellForRow` to add tapGesture to the cell ... as cell get reuse so same gesture will apply to multiple cells. So instead of adding it in cell for row .. add them in Custom cell `init()` method in your case in `CustomTableViewCell` class so it adds only once ... you can set Tag to that gesture in `cellForRow` method that will not cause any issue ...